# how to recover auto removed files by github in vscode?

Tags: github

I've been pushing my code to github and recently i've been working on one page. and i've made a backup of that page in my local storage. but when i try to sync my code with the one in github, it crushed and deleted the folder i've been working on.

not only just that it removed it from other repo and even from my other github projects. and it's not even in my trash. How can i recover averything?